# How to find gradle implementation path for a dependency?

Tags: android, gradle, repository, implementation, android-library

Whenever I find a component I want to use it's impossible to find the dependency path + version for it.

I would assume it would be stated in the documentation or that there is a reference to it on the repository's Git Hub page, but this have never been the case!

For example, what do I need to implement in order to use [GrantPermissionRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule)?
Or, what do I implement if I *only* need to use the [Material repository](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android)?

It has to be a standard I'm not aware of.
For example each Flutter package always have the package path at the top of each Repository/ReadMe/PubDart page, and both are maintained by the same company!

Comment: After two years of Android development, followed by one year of Flutter, I'm not sure if it was always this way or if I just forgot how to Android.

Comment: This has sort of always been the way. There's no standard about where people put the Gradle/Maven coordinates for the libraries, you just have to look through the docs. E.g for material components, the instructions are here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look here in the first place: https://mvnrepository.com/
Here is for example list of androidx.test dependencies: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.test

Comment: If you expand on this answer I will mark is as the answer.
Where would you find the path from here?(ie. click version, select gradle copy and paste in app build.gradel). Also, how can you reformat the odd looking string to the more conventional format `implementation group:name:version`.

Comment: Also the link was to the wrong library. Here is the right one `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.test/rules`. I appreciate your answer and it solved my issue. I just want the next person finding this to have a complete explanation.